# Sorting Tuples Python

Tags: python, tuples

I want to sort tuples using this method...

If (a1,b1) < (a2,b2)  then a2>a1 or (a1==a2 and b2>b1).

The algorithm should not work in place, and it's expected that it will receive numbers in the range [0,99].

```
Input:
[(9, 7), (78, 24), (17, 74), (53, 81), (40, 43), (79, 82), (84, 46), (68, 53),
(92, 95), (60, 38), (20, 62), (72, 57)]
Output:
[(9, 7), (17, 74), (20, 62), (40, 43), (53, 81), (60, 38), (68, 53), (72, 57),
(78, 24), (79, 82), (84, 46), (92, 95)]
```

I thought of using the concept of counting sort since the time complexity has to be O(n), but then the list counter length would be 100*100. That wouldn't be a very efficient approach.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This should work out of the box. Try `sorted(input_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

[`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) built-in function should work just fine for your case, it compares the first element and if the first element is the same for two items, it then compares the 2nd element, etc.

In the following example, `simple_list[0][0]` and `simple_list[1][0]` are equal (4 and 4), so `simple_list[0][1]` and `simple_list[1][1]` (3 and 5) are compared:

```
>>> simple_list = [(4, 3), (4, 5), (1, 2)]
>>> sorted(simple_list)
[(1, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5)]
```

For your case, try the following:

```
tuples_list = [(9, 7), (78, 24), (17, 74), (53, 81), (40, 43), (79, 82), (84, 46), (68, 53), (92, 95), (60, 38), (20, 62), (72, 57)]

sorted_list = sorted(tuples_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> sorted(tuples_list)
[(9, 7), (17, 74), (20, 62), (40, 43), (53, 81), (60, 38), (68, 53), (72, 57), (78, 24), (79, 82), (84, 46), (92, 95)]
```